# For Dropbox API is there a way to pull a list of users and see if MFA is enabled?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am wanting to pull all users in my company dropbox and then check to see if their accounts have MFA enabled.  I read over the documentation for Dropbox api but did not see anything stand out where this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's very sad to realize that a popular platform such as Dropbox doesn't expose A LOT of basic features through its API (and the SDK itself is far from being OK, compared to G-Suite). Anyway, there are two hacky methods you can use in order to pull out that information (with some limitations).

**First method:**

By analyzing the `team events` using `team_members_list()` you can filter out `tfa_change_status_details` events. When `new_value=TfaConfiguration('[sms|other]', None)` is specified - 2FA is enabled.
The information I found out that can be retrieved using this method is:

- *has_2fa* - whether 2FA was ever configured.
- *is_tfa_enabled* - whether 2FA is currently enabled.
- *tfa_type* - whether 2FA is by SMS or by app.

However, keep in mind that you have to track changes constantly and also keep in mind that Dropbox saves team events for only two years.

**Second method:**

Using the front-end dashboard API this information can be retrieved (I can't remember the API name, I think that it is `/2/get_multifactor` and inside you'd find some information about its status and the organizational policy regarding 2FA). However, to use the front-end dashboard API (which is totally undocumented) you'd need to simulate a successful login (and correctly use the `lid` and `jar` cookies) and you'd also need to bypass the random captcha that appears when you abuse the service with too many requests.

To be honest, Dropbox's API is weak, neglected, and ugly. I wish I never had to use it. Anyway, I would recommend using the first method and pray for a significant update to the API

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately the Dropbox API doesn't expose this. We'll consider it a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature request open for this one (https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/MFA-status-for-users/m-p/468564#M23886). But I wouldn't hold your breath, as @Aviv mentioned the Dropbox API seems surprisingly neglected at the moment.